# Indexing in a nested list with strings

Tags: indexing, python-3.7, nested-lists

I am trying to access each index in the nested list. The first item is a string though and so instead I get the first 3 letters from the string.

[image]

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

You've confused the names.  `cinfo` is your original tuple.  `clist` is your list with one element, the tuple.  You are printing from `cinfo`, when you meant to use `clist`.